# not understanding the call user function example in php.net

Tags: php

I am not understanding the following example in php.net. can anyone explain ?

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a = 0;
call_user_func('increment', $a);
echo $a."\n";

// You can use this instead
call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a));
echo $a."\n";
?>
```

What array(&$a) means? what will the intial value of $a?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a));

Comment: What array(&$a) means? what will the intial value of $a?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/3933332

Comment: Would you understand what is going on if you called `increment()` directly without `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()`? If so, your question topic is just misleading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) state that "parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference". In the given example

```
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}
call_user_func('increment', $a);
```

the value of `$a` will not be incremented, PHP will raise a warning `Parameter 1 to increment() expected to be a reference, value given` instead. Code inside the callabe will not be executed, the result of `call_user_func()` however is NULL.

You cannot call the funtion with `call_user_func('increment', &$a)` either, since `Call-time pass-by-reference` has been removed in PHP 5.4.
This is what the example is supposed to demonstrate.

Using `call_user_func_array()` allows the parameter to be passed as reference, so the result of

```
$a = 0;
call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a));
```

is 1.

To use the callable without a reference, `return` the value from the function and assign this return value to $a instead:

```
function increment($var)
{
    $var++;
    return $var;
}

$a = 0;
$a = call_user_func('increment', $a);
print 'a: ' . $a . PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
a: 1
```

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}


call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a));
echo $a."\n";
?> output 1 how? bcz I didnt assign any value to $a?

Comment: You don't have to, it's a reference, the value of `$a` was `(int) 0` before the function call. For further explanations follow the link Rizier123 gave in their comment above.